# Mongoose – querying subdocuments referenced by ID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 schemas connected like this:

```
const Brand = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: { type: String, required: true },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  products: [{
    type: String,
    ref: 'Product',
  }],
});

const Product = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: { type: String, required: true },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  type: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

I want to find brands that have certain types of products, so I wrote a query (not including async/await and promises in the code below for simplicity)

```
const docs = Brand.find({ 'products.type': 'my-type-here' })
      .populate([
        {
          path: 'products',
        },
      ])
      .sort({ index: 1 })
      .exec();
```

This gives me 0 results, yet I know that there are brand with the type of products. What am I doing wrong here? Is it connected with the fact, that products are only referenced by their ids when I invoke `find` method?

Comment: Instead of type string in ref define mongoose.Schema.ObjectId making it
products: [{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,ref: 'Product',}]

Comment: Is there any way I can do it with the `type: String`? I encountered a problem when seeding records to the database when having `type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId` and would like to avoid it.

Comment: Try using this for that instead
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals